# RadFileExplorer Customize alert popup if folder already present

Tags: telerik, telerik-ajax

I am using telerik ASP.Net Ajax RadFileExplorer. When the user tries to add a folder which is already present in the path radfileexplorer displays an alert popup stating "An object with the same name already exists in this directory!".

My question is "Is it possible to display the same content in a radWindow popup instead of an alert box"?

Answer (score 0):

You can: Calling it from client will be:

```
<button onclick="radconfirm('Client radconfirm: Are you sure?', confirmCallBackFn, 330, 180, null, 'Client RadConfirm', $dialogsDemo.imgUrl); return false;">
                This folder already exists, are you sure?
</button>
```

Check this to have more examples https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/window/examples/browserdialogboxes/defaultcs.aspx?show-source=true

Comment: Thanks for the answer.My question is related to functionality of radfileexplorer. I knew about radconfirm popup.But my question is how to circumvent the radfileexplorer from displaying an alert popup in the first place.